# PHP Error constant for error_get_last function

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there a constant or env. variable that stores the last error created? The one that is returned via error_get_last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to be sarcastic (well, yes, but only a little), but you do know the PHP manual has a "See also" section, right? Looking at the page for `error_get_last()`, I found this little gem: [The $php_errormsg variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php)

Of course, that variable has some limitation (i.e. only works in the scope that the error occurred in, and only if `track_errors` is on).

But actually, why do you want to use a variable. The point of `error_get_last()` is to give you the last error, so why not use that?

Comment: I know I could use that function, I just needed to know if there was a way to access a constant inline instead. Weird edge-case. Thx.